# How to access java servlet session attribute in angular js application

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, session, servlets

How to access servlet session attribute in angular js application, in the example the ProductServlet is setting the products in a session attribute, how to acess this variable in the AngularJs application, what is the equivalent of this

```
public class ProductServlet extends HttpServlet {
.....
...
    List<Products> products = getProducts();// Return the List of the products
    if (session.getAttribute("userName") == null) {
            session.setAttribute("products", products);
        }
......
......
}
```

My Angular JS controller

```
 function ProductController($scope, $http)
    {
      $scope.user = {};

      $scope. GetProducts = function() 
      {
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/Products',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          data:  $scope.user
        }).success(function (data) 
          {
            $scope.status=data;
          });
      };
    }
```

The HTML

```
<body>
    <form ng-controller="ProductController" ng-submit="GetProducts()">
    <legend>Get Productsr</legend>


      <button class="btn btn-primary">Get Products</button>
      <br/>
      <label>DISPLAY the List of products</label>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot just access server-side data (such as attributes) from Javascript running in the browser.

You'd have to create some web service to expose this data (for example to JSON GET requests).

And if you do that, make sure that no one unauthorized can access this information.

Comment: That means all the Legacy Application that runs on the JSP-Servlet model, has to be migrated